# How do you change a background color of the body type only for certain pages in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with Laravel right now and can't figure out how I can apply different background colors on different pages when I am using partials and extends in blade.php.

Comment: apply css for each page? or use js to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a variable for a class:

```
<body class="{{ $body_class }}">
```

Then return that variable from your controller when you want:

```
return view('whatever', [
   'body_class' => 'bg-blue'
]);
```

And of course, define your classes in your stylesheet:

```
.bg-blue { background-color: blue }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above works great... but recommend this when you add the variable to the  tag:

```
<body class= "{{ $body_class ?? '' }}" >
```

That way if your body_class is not assigned by the controller, the page will still render.

Comment: You should avoid relative terms like "The above" when referencing other people's answers because answers have no fixed order and "The above" eventually will change. You could reference previous answers by including the answers authors name f.e.